# Using $(this) in coffeescript

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, this

just a quick one. How is it possible to use jQuery `$(this)` in [Coffeescript](http://coffeescript.org/):

```
$ 'input'
 .on 'click', (e) ->
  alert 'test' if $ 'this'
   .is(':checked')
```

can't get it to work.

Comment: ehhhh.... `$(this)`?

Comment: `this` and `'this'` are completely different things.

Comment: @muistooshort of course they are, that's what the question is about. I thought `$ 'this'` will render to `$(this)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').on('click', 
  (e) ->
   if $(this).is(':checked')
     alert('test')
)
```

`':checked'` not `:checked`

use paranthesis - it will save your time. Trust me.